# Open 2 webpages on link click

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have an IFrame on a webpage, and upon clicking on a hyperlink, I need to be able to refresh the IFrame AND ALSO open a different website in a new browser window, any help at all is greatly appreciiated.

Thank you

jase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
<a href="otherpage.html" TARGET="_NEW" onClick="window.location.reload()">Reload  and open</a>
```

ought to work

Comment: thanks bemace, is there a way to add ?t=true to the end of the location.reload? so i can handle the t using php when it reloads?

Comment: In that case you'd be doing a redirect.  Searching for "javascript redirect" should give you plenty of info, but basically you just need window.location="http://someplace.com?t=true"